# Self-Selection Bias Intrinsic to Survey Samples?

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm new to stats so bear with me in asking this question. I'm sure my novice will shine through.

I've noticed that with *any* survey there is an intrinsic opportunity for self-selection bias
(There is a difference between those willing to complete the survey and those asked who refuse to do so).

Will this difference be taken into account when determining the measure of reliability for any inference drawn from the survey sample? If not should there be a consideration of the fact that everyone who completes the survey has been effectively self-selected?

Answer (score 1):

The "intrinsic" opportunity for self-selection is usually eliminated in the early stages. If you're doing this in real-life (as opposed to just as a mental exercise) you initially try to determine the response rate of your survey.

If it is lower than average for your type of questionnaire you likely have problems with your question design, and should fix that before going further. Once you've determined the response rate, you can determine the number of people you should sample so as to get sufficient responses for a reliable result.

Comment: So response rate + questionnaire type is used as a proxy to determine whether or not abnormal conditions were created in the sample due to self-selection? What does question design have to do with response rate? The group I'm referring to as 'those who are self-selected' is everyone who decides to complete the survey.

Comment: You're not trying to determine abnormal conditions in the *sample*. There may be issues in the *questionnaire* or there may be issues with the *sample*. If your initial response rate differs from what others have done, you likely have a problem with your questions. If, for some reason, your response rate is higher than average, your chosen sample may have not random from the beginning. Of course, there are situations where you don't want your sample to be random, and are specifically seeking bias.

Comment: @Jeremy Oh, and the question design has a great deal to do with the response rate. If the questions aren't clear and easily understood, people may not answer. If the survey is too long, again people may not answer all of it. If the questions are too sensitive/personal, again that has a huge impact on the response rate and the accuracy of the results. If you're asking people about their fidelity, criminal activity, etc. those are sensitive questions where people do lie.